# Is it possible to fetch data from a key?

Tags: openssl, rsa, m2crypto

Is it possible to get any user readable data from key like below

```
uchar DELTA_PUB_KEY[]  = {
0x7c, 0x5b, 0x31, 0x88, 0x25, 0x64, 0x43, 0xaa,
0x34, 0x97, 0x6b, 0x7d, 0x22, 0x9a, 0x56, 0xdd,
0x5e, 0xab, 0x2f, 0xd6, 0x10, 0x34, 0x12, 0x6b,
0x12, 0xfa, 0x34, 0x54, 0x33, 0xee, 0x32, 0xde,
0x13, 0x54, 0x12, 0x23, 0x98, 0x7e, 0xe6, 0xee
0x34, 0x72, 0x91, 0xfb, 0x67, 0x98, 0x56, 0x34
};
```

I got a requirement to see what is there inside a key similar to above.

And also what is the information I should get with the below command

```
To print out the components of a private key to standard output:

     openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout
```

Will that command be used to get the required data? I think it is not possible to read any information from a key, but I need your opinion. Please help me in getting the data from a key.

Comment: Why is this tagged `m2crypto`? Your code example doesn't appear to be Python.

Comment: I am a python developer and used M2Crypto in my applications. I thought of knowing if any M2Crypto users is succeeded in reading data from key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a key in a structured format, such as a PEM-encoded RSAPrivateKey ASN.1 object, then you can use tools such as OpenSSL to print some information. Typically this will just be the labelled parts of the key.

For instance, running `openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout` would produce something like:

```
Private-Key: (512 bit)
modulus:
    00:bd:50:d9:87:f5:67:0f:61:f2:4d:f9:0b:5c:c5:
    0b:4d:c2:c9:7b:b4:fc:b0:d5:65:0e:ea:b8:36:33:
    3a:18:2d:1a:41:76:e5:46:b3:d3:35:34:29:85:ac:
    d2:2b:c5:d8:0b:30:80:9f:d5:dd:64:c3:d3:61:32:
    f9:67:8c:e9:4b
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    38:ad:0f:b2:a8:41:26:55:c8:58:97:8a:53:47:9a:
    4e:b9:55:e0:77:1a:7f:46:23:6f:07:ce:06:4b:e7:
    c4:7c:97:bd:e7:02:f6:0b:28:14:24:d5:b9:48:23:
    a1:2c:01:bf:cd:60:40:a9:42:82:7e:1e:73:71:87:
    4b:58:d5:61
prime1:
    00:f3:0a:f4:7f:48:84:f3:d2:3c:f0:5b:25:d2:f5:
    46:76:b5:cf:7d:d3:39:37:03:ba:56:08:2e:ec:01:
    3b:0c:35
prime2:
    00:c7:68:a1:2e:22:53:03:83:27:f2:28:6a:54:f2:
    57:0c:d6:75:d5:ad:d9:ef:08:75:ab:ac:6b:18:59:
    37:cf:7f
exponent1:
    4a:52:5a:4c:26:18:0a:1b:8b:69:10:e6:73:29:70:
    3f:d2:ff:3d:81:ff:28:14:aa:c1:ae:44:f3:04:b9:
    52:d5
exponent2:
    70:39:37:34:b2:86:8b:9c:7d:97:b0:1d:1f:8f:7f:
    64:2f:32:03:be:a2:be:fe:c0:d2:8b:e7:7d:bd:80:
    46:5b
coefficient:
    00:81:44:0f:d2:71:a7:40:d1:31:43:4e:04:ce:c3:
    e4:67:fb:aa:8a:bc:dc:86:7a:74:7f:65:94:b5:b3:
    b4:f1:23
```

The example data you supplied doesn't appear to be ASN.1, so I'm not sure what information you could derive from it. It's only 40 bytes, so perhaps it's the modulus of a 320-bit RSA public key? If so, that's incredibly weak and not really worth using.

Comment: Sorry, that is a sample key only as I don't have permission to post the actual key. That is just to show that my key is similar. I have updated 8 more bytes making total of 48 bytes.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Is it a valid sample key? Or just a bunch of random bytes you invented?

Comment: Sorry if it caused any inconvenience to you, but it is a bunch of random bytes

Comment: @RajeshKumar Ok, well it's impossible for me to advise further then. I have no idea what format your data is in.

Comment: Thank you, any way your information has helped me that it is not possible to get any information from key except the labelled parts